# Adjusting All dates from Trialforce Source Organizations

Tags: managed-package, trial, trialforce

We are creating a TSO template to give trials of our managed package to our customers. In our package, we have multiple custom objects and custom fields that we want to be created dynamically based on the creation day of the trial. I know the checkbox shown below updates createddates and modified dates on records based on the creation date of the trial. [image]

We want custom fields of type datetime/date on custom objects in the TSO org to be also adjusted. Does this checkbox work for those as well? If not, how can we do that? The goal is to have realistic dates on our custom objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It will. I created a trial from the template and all the custom fields were adjusted similar to standard object dates.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know - all date fields should be updated - and the method is according to this:

[How does "Adjust All Dates in the Resulting Organization Relative to Organization Creation Date" on Trialforce template creation work](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213315&language=en_US)

Anyhow, if this is not enough - you can create a simple class in the managed package that sets your dates, and after package installation run this class.